# What is the ambiguous use mean

Tags: swift

Here is the code that compiler tell me it is ambiguous:

```
        aTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil),
            forCellReuseIdentifier:"MyTableViewCell")
```

and it don't have ambiguous problems:

```
        var tmpCell = UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

        aTableView.registerNib(tmpCell,
            forCellReuseIdentifier:"MyTableViewCell")
```

I can't see any differences between these two. Why the compiler tell me it is ambiguous? Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I copied your code and pasted it and it compiled fine. You are not showing the actual problem. Show your real code, show enough of it, and show the actual error message. _Don't type; copy and paste._

Comment: (And why would anyone call a nib a cell?)

Comment: @matt he probably uses it as a table view cell.

Comment: you might have done this: ```aTableView.registerNib(nib: UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier:"MyTableViewCell")```.  In Xcode 6 you have to remove the nib: from the first method param.